# Как заполнить массив определенным количеством раз с определенным значением

Tags: c#

не могу придумать метод, который должен заполнять массив рандомными значениями true or false, но с ограничениями по false; Допустим, что надо в массиве максимум 2 false, а остальное true.

Пример:

bool[] array = new bool[5];

[true,false,true,true,false]

Как это можно реализовать, ибо никак не могу придумать?

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерируйте случайное число f в пределах max_false, заполните массив f значений false и len-f значений true, после чего перемешайте массив с помощью shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Заполняете массив `true`, потом в цикле от 0 до <2 (или сколько требуется) генерите случайные индексы в пределах массива, куда ставите `false`. Если индексы не совпадут, то будет ровно 2 `false`, если совпадут - будет 1 `false`, что удовлетворяет условию "максимум 2 `false`"